# How to Perfectly stop DispatcherTimer in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, dispatcher

In my project, when I started and finished the timer with the 'start button' and 'stop button' first time, it would work normally.

But when I pressed the 'start button' again without turning off the program, it started to insert data twice per interval as if two timers were working.

The third and fourth time I repeated, it showed an insertion error as much.

There's  my summarized code below, I think it's not a complete stop. It's a pause and overlap i think.

Did i do something wrong?

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
     { DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

     private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
             timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
             timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
             timer.Start();
         }

     private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             //data insert
         }

     private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
             timer.Stop();
         }
}
```

Comment: have you checked if you are just adding new events? maybe you need to remove them also if you want to keep clicking.

Comment: @GiulioCaccin Why would you check that? It is obvious from the code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding a new Tick handler each time you click the Button. You may also want to check if the timer is already running before starting it again. Otherwise you would reset the interval.

Move the first two lines of btnStart_Click to a Window1 constructor:

```
private readonly DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

public Window1()
{
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
}

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!timer.IsEnabled)
    {
        timer.Start();
    }
}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //data insert
}
```

As further improvements you could do the following:

- enable and disable the Start and Stop Buttons according to the IsEnabled state of the timer
- replace the two Buttons by a single ToggleButton
- bind the ToggleButton's IsChecked property to the IsEnabled property of the timer.
- move the timer code to a view model